# How to fix resolution problems while playing in wine?

Tags: wine, games, intel-graphics, display-resolution, ram

I'm pretty noob at Linux.

I run ubuntu 16.04 lts on a dual boot system with windows 7

- Intel Pentium B950 (2x2.10ghz)
- Intel Sandy Bridge Graphic Card
- 4Gb DDR3

I installed wine and installed some games.

Now I tried playing them and sometimes they work but never in widescreen resolution (If I adjusted the resolution it just images a widescreen into a square which is pretty anoying) So it drops a big part of my screen.
But most of the times the game starts with the desktop menu next to it:

[image: screenshot]

Is it possible this has something to do with my RAM? I had some memory dumps (0x00000050) in windows and if I do a memory test it sometimes gives some errors, sometimes nothing, which is pretty odd.

Or is it a graphic setting in wine or Linux?

Also,if I play it starts out running very smooth, but after 20min to a half hour it starts to lag, without the laptop overheating too much.

Are these all related or are they individual problems? I was thinking replacing the 4gb ram (which may be broken) by a new 8gb ddr3, although it seems overkill since my graphic card and processor cant even follow 4gb ram.

Comment: don't use a virtual desktop with wine, or change the resolution of the virtual desktop

Comment: Virtual desktop is disabled. Im using it without but sometimes it displays it like that,thats the problem

Comment: hmmm, and with a virtual desktop?

Comment: Its difficult to find the right resolution, I add the same resolution as my desktop is, and still some parts of the screen that are not visual on display